# Hyperlink in Popup window in C#

Tags: c#, redirect, hyperlink, popup, navigateurl

the following Hyperlink is in the popup written in C#.

```
var hypLink = new HyperLink
{
    Text = "Order Nummer",
    NavigateUrl = "~/Order.Page.aspx?OrderID=00001001"
};
```

The above code is redirecting the `Order.Page.aspx` inside the popup.

But I am trying, When user clicks on the hyperlink:

1. the popup should close.
2. redirect to the NavigateUrl `~/Order.Page.aspx?OrderID=00001001`

Answer (score 0):

One of the options you have is using javascript code. You add your window that you want to close in my_window variable, and with custom method closepopup() you can close your popup window.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


   my_window = window.open("", "mywindow","status=1,width=350,height=150");

   function closepopup()
   {
      if(false == my_window.closed)
      {
         my_window.close ();
      }
      else
      {
         alert('Window already closed!');
      }
   }
</script>

<body>
   <p>
      <a href="javascript: closepopup()">Close the Popup Window</a>
   </p>
</body>
```

Another option is to try this attribute that Hyperlink has:

```
var hypLink = new HyperLink
{
    Text = "Order Nummer",
    NavigateUrl = "~/Order.Page.aspx?OrderID=00001001"
};

    hypLink.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.close()")
```

Comment: I tried with your second option. But it is not working.